# PHP associative array: unique function to value

Tags: php, associative-array

So due to some nasty framework issues, I'm a little stuck here.  Basically, I'm taking a string from user input, and replacing it with a value from my model that is only known at call time.

My structures are like so:

```
static public $placeholders = array("[REPLACE_STRING_1]"=>'firstName',
                                    "[REPLACE_STRING_2]"=>'DateTime->format(\'aa,bb\')');
//Problem line above.  Very messy, format is an arm long and painful

public function myfunction(ModelClass $master) {
    $body = $this->sampleService->get('samplebody'); // populate body from DB
    foreach(static::$placeholders as $key => $value){
        $body = str_replace($key, $master->value, $body);
    }
    return $body;
}
```

So this makes for some very ugly code.  My boss would like to edit it to make for a function to be part of the array, assigned to each entry, that would run to filter/edit the code.  Something like

```
function dateFormat($prop){
    return $prop->format('aa,bb');
}
function asIs($prop){
    return $prop;
}

static public $placeholders = array("[REPLACE_STRING_1]"=>['firstName', asIs]
                                    "[REPLACE_STRING_2]"=>['DateTime', dateFormat]);
```

Are there any existing structures or functions in PHP which make this possible, or is his code desire just a pipedream?

EDIT:  I figured out a solution very similar to the answer posted below, but with a few modifications necessary to pass along variables.

```
function dateFormat ($prop, $master) {
    return $master->$prop->format('aabb');
}
function asIs ($prop, $master) {
    return $appointment->$prop;
}
static public $placeholders = array("[REPLACE_STRING_1]"=>['firstname','asIs'], 
                                    "[REPLACE_STRING_2]"=>['DateTime', dateFormat];

//instatiate service to get sampleService values

//main difference here
public function buildBody(ModelClass $master) {
    $body = $this->sampleService->get('samplebody');
    foreach(static::$placeholders as $key => $value){
        $body = preg_replace_callback('/'.preg_quote($key).'/',
        //Use closure here to pass in $master, otherwise laravel gets angry about strings instead of objects
        function ($matches) use ($master) {
            $placeholder = static::placeholders[$matches[0]];
            $func = $placeholder[1];
            $prop = $placeholder[0];
            return call_user_func(array($this, $func), $prop, $appointment);
        }, $body);
    }
    return $body;
}
```

All in all this was a very interesting problem for me, and I'm trying to find a way to clean it up even further.  Going to mark your answer as correct, since it greatly helped get here.

Comment: Have you tried what your boss wants? What are the results?

Comment: At the moment, it's a syntax error.  I'm not sure if there's a way to apply a function to an associative array declaration inline.

Comment: Tell your boss that it can't be done with PHP. You'd need to have a getter method which calls the functions and returned the result - can't be done at call time

Comment: I'm still not clear quite what you're after, but my spidey-sense is saying you should look into call_user_func or call_user_func_array to call functions dynamically and get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got the question right, I'd go with `preg_replace_callback` and do it somewhat like this:

```
function dateFormat($prop){
    return $prop;
}

function asIs($prop){
    return $prop;
}

static public $placeholders = array(
    "[REPLACE_STRING_1]"=>['firstName', 'asIs'],
    "[REPLACE_STRING_2]"=>['DateTime', 'dateFormat']
);

private function replace($matches) {
    $placeholder = static::$placeholders[$matches[0]];
    $func = $placeholder[1];
    $prop = $placeholder[0];

    // this calls your class methods ('asIs', 'dateFormat')
    // with $prop = 'firstName' etc.
    return call_user_func(array($this, $func), $prop);
}

public function myfunction(ModelClass $master) {
    $body = $this->sampleService->get('samplebody');

    foreach(static::$placeholders as $key => $value) {
        // use a callback replace method instead of str_replace
        $body = preg_replace_callback('/' . preg_quote($key) . '/', array($this, 'replace'), $body);
    }

    return $body;
}
```

Comment: I'll try this out today and see if it works, but that should be what I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: Coming really close to working, but running into a snag.

When I call DateFormat, it needs to be $master->$value->format(), due to the constraints that laravel places.  it seems that if I set value[0] to $master-$value[0] before I pass it in, it still considers it of type string, instead of inheriting from the type of $master.

Comment: You could try adding `$master` to the placeholder in myfunction `static::$placeholders['REPLACE_STRING_2'][2] = $master;` and in `function replace` pass it as another parameter to `function dateFormat($prop, $master)` (`return call_user_func(array($this, $func), $prop, $placeholder[2]);`)

Comment: Just to answer your why, that wouldn't work since master is an argument to buildbody, it's the instance of the model which contains data to be replaced into a template.  So I can't have it in a static object.  But thanks for the help.

Comment: You can add another property `private $master` to the class and set your variable to that: `$this->master = $master` or as a reference maybe: `$this->master = &$master` and use that in your functions.